# How to make running Bayesian model in RStan on HPC cluster more efficient?

Tags: r, bayesian, hpc, rstan

I am using a high-performance computing cluster to run a dynamic Bayesian latent variable model in RStan.
Here is the code to run the model:

```
# run the Stan model 
mod.dyn <- stan(file="DynamicLVMFinal.stan",
                data=stan.data, seed=570175513, thin = 5,
                iter=10000)
```

Here is the submission script I am using for the HPC cluster:

```
#!/bin/bash  module load r/4.1.0 sbatch -p general -N 1 --mem=125g -n 150 -t 7- --wrap="Rscript /nas/longleaf/home/bwhecht/DynamicLVM/Power_Dyn_Minimum.R"
```

As you can see, I am currently requesting 1 task, 125 gb of memory, and 150 CPUS. I am wondering if I am sufficiently optimizing the process. How can I tweak this (the model code and/or the submission script) to make the run time more efficient? The model currently takes about 5-6 days to run using the above code.

Comment: There's a lot we don't know here.  How many chains are you running? Is your Stan code explicitly parallelized (see [here](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_23/stan-users-guide/parallelization-chapter.html))?  Whether Stan can make use of 150 CPUs or not is very problem-dependent (I *think* that if you don't explicitly parallelize then you only use as many cores as you have chains).  You will almost certainly need to do some benchmarking and testing of alternative options, with a small enough subset of the data to be quick and large enough subset to be informative (e.g. a 1% or 0.1% sample)

Comment: Also, benchmarking with only 100 or 1000 iterations (possibly in addition to a subset of the data) should help you figure out what you need to do much faster. You can use `gc()` and or the `peakRAM` package to figure out how much memory is actually used; requesting more memory than you need won't speed up computation and might reduce your priority/availability of HPC resources.